# Does QGIS still support standalone PyQGIS application development (outside of QGIS program)?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, standalone

We have developed a few PyQGIS standalone applications that bring in `PyQt5.Qtcore, PyQt5.QtGui, and qgis.core` to display map and do custom logics etc. The applications started with QGIS python 2.7 all the way to QGIS python 3.6, over time we found that it is getting increasingly difficult to get the libraries setup correctly and packaging the application.

I would like to emphasize that these are applications that are completely standalone without needing to open QGIS program, they are NOT run from inside QGIS's python console.

Now, it is QGIS 3.16 LTR with Python 3.8, after upgrade QGIS, our apps stopped working, this happens pretty much every time there is a new version of QGIS. The QGIS installation structure changed a lot with this new version (just like previous version changes), to name a few things for example, `apps/qt5/include` and `apps/qt5/doc` directories are no longer there, and the following imports are no longer working:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QUndoCommand, QUndoStack, QFileDialog, QVBoxLayout, QAction
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAbstractItemView, QMessageBox, QMenu, QInputDialog, QDockWidget
```

Does QGIS still intend to support standalone application development or should we abandon these apps and build plugins instead? I could NOT find an up-to-date programmer's guide for developing standalone applications, most of the PDF instruction files on the internet are for much older versions of QGIS.

A bit more information about our application setup. We develop using PyCharm on Windows 10 OS, and we install QGIS using its installer, not from package, for example, for this latest version, we used `QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.16.11-1.msi` and install into `C:\OSGeo4W64` directory, then in PyCharm, we set python interpreter to `C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python39\python.exe` (the last version was pointing to `Python36\python.exe`), this will pull in all packages that come with the QGIS software and this has been the way we've been developing the applications. This is because from past experience (since QGIS python 2.7), we have to use all python libraries/packages that come with QGIS inside its own installation directories, because it appears that the qgis.core is built with its own versions of every package that is included in QGIS software itself. We tried in the past to point to outside PyQt libraries and couldn't get qgis.core to work in standalone application until we reference everything back into QGIS software itself.

We look forward to hearing a more definitive answer and any migration tips/guide.

Comment: In my opinion, this question is more suitable for the QGIS-dev mailing list, where most of devs and even members of the PSC will read your question. https://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/qgis-developer

Comment: On QGIS's main page under user community, gis.stackexchange.com is prominently listed as a place to ask any QGIS questions: https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/support.html StackExchange¶
On http://gis.stackexchange.com you can ask QGIS questions also. If you use the tag qgis you’ll see all QGIS related questions and answers: http://gis.stackexchange.com/?tags=qgis; also, this question doesn't relate to any of the things you listed:  licensing, pricing, release dates, submission of bug reports and enhancement requests, it strictly is related to the issue with QGIS library per app development

Comment: Your question relates to QGIS product planning so it pertains to the business of the QGIS development team, and can only be answered definitively by them.

Comment: Pretty sure standalone apps are still supported. I can import those modules from my qgis python console. Maybe you've not installed everything? Post a minimal PyQGIS application and the error you get, and operating system and version numbers etc and maybe we can track this down.

Comment: This problem is at your end, your packaging is broken.

Comment: @Spacedman I am not talking about doing things inside QGIS python console, I am talking about complete standalone application that doesn't require opening QGIS.

Comment: @bugmenot123 Yes, I know the problem is at our application end, but that is precisely what my question is about, that is: our standalone applications were built based on past instructions from QGIS's programmer's guide, now the new versions of QGIS programs are not honoring those library structural convention any more without publishing new guide.

Comment: Try to change all `PyQt5` in import section to `qgis.PyQt`. For example: `from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui` into `from qgis.PyQt import QtCore, QtGui`.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz Wow, that worked for that import, it looks like all PyQt namespaces are moved under qgis namespace now. See, this is exactly the kind of things we need guidance of. But there are hundreds upon hundreds of different libraries' references would need to be updated. So ***IF*** we were to try to update, is there an updated guide document somewhere, or do we just have to brute force looking at QGIS's source code (actually even that wouldn't help in some cases) ... Then again, this brings the question, should we just abandon this effort??

Comment: @ForComment what I'm saying is that any well-setup standalone PyQGIS application should have the same access to python modules as the QGIS python console for the same version of the QGIS base installation and Python interpreter. If your QGIS main app can import something from the console but your standalone PyQGIS app can't, then your setup is broken.

Comment: Could you add a link to the "past instructions from QGIS's programmer's guide" , then maybe we can try to find the documentation issue. Also you might want to post the script you use for startup, including the PATH etc.

Comment: @bugmenot123 there used to be a PDF file for develop PyQGIS application cookbook that was published by QGIS team for QGIS Python 2.7, I have not seen anything like that for free on the web for QGIS python 3, most are users' personal blogs etc such as [this one](https://anitagraser.com/2019/03/03/stand-alone-pyqgis-scripts-with-osgeo4w/) [this one actually is similar to our setup], but nothing official from QGIS team.

Comment: @Spacedman, I would like to reiterate that our app worked fine when we were referencing libraries inside QGIS installation when it was QGIS 3.6 version, but now after installing this new version and our setup has not changed one bit, those imports are all failing now, we have been through this same dynamic everytime a new QGIS version is used, there always is something changed without documentation and we have to fight through to get those synched up with whatever QGIS version in use. Just look at Kadir's reply above, that's enough proof that namespaces are changed without documentation.

Comment: I deleted my answer since I thought it was not an adequate answer to your question. Your question a bit broad. I have not enough English and time to explain broadly. My answer is just a part of the solution, I guess.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz, I think you should repost your solution, because it is actually "part of the solution" to my question, just like you said, and it is true! and it will serve the greater QGIS user community greatly, please repost your solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Standalone PyQGIS application are still supported. I'm still developing apps.

I had the same problem at the beginning of developing standalone PyQGIS3 apps. Changing all `PyQt5` in import section to `qgis.PyQt` solved the PyQt issue. For example:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
```

to

```
from qgis.PyQt import QtCore, QtGui
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import *
```

Comment: Actually, earlier versions of QGIS in python 3 (e.g. the 3.6 version/Noosa) actually used the PyQt5 namespace. What's more, when packaging our app, we discovered that there needs to be a standalone 'src' folder that contains some of the key libraries that needs to be distributed with the packaged program. I have not tried with this new version yet. But I am frustrated in that it seems that every version of QGIS, these namespaces change without warning/documentation, which makes standalone application development increasingly dicey.

Comment: Our app also has an import: `import sip`, it is not working anymore, I clearly see 'sip' package in the QGIS site-packages, but it is not recognizing it with this new version, perhaps it is referenced via different namespace now? thx.

Comment: Where have all of the QtWidgets gone? i.e. `QApplication, QMainWindow, QMenu` etc etc are all missing. I tried multiple namespaces paths, none leads to any of the QtWidgets! When I navigate to QtWidget declaration in PyCharm, it still says import PyQt5 !

Comment: `import sip` to `from qgis.PyQt import sip` Look at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/wiki/Plugin-migration-to-QGIS-3#minimal-info (for plugin but could help to upgrade). See also https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html#qgis_api_break_3_0

Comment: @ThomasG77 this works! so two down, more to go in our upgrade effort. I think that we've already followed that qgis api break link you posted when we migrated from QGIS python 2.7 to QGIS python 3 during last round of upgrade. I hope we can spur some effort towards official cookbook development for standalone app development, well, until QGIS state otherwise. I am hoping for clarity.

Comment: @ThomasG77 I just followed through the QGIS/wiki page you posted, but one of the biggest migration tip is not working. That page suggested this: from `qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QMainWindow`, but it doesn't work on our windows 10 dev environment (look at my question above for details), it says `Cannot find reference 'QMainWindow' in 'QtWidgets.py'` in pycharm, and indeed there is nothing defined in the `QtWidgets.py` that comes with the new QGIS installation. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: In my QGIS root dir, I got `share/qgis/python/qgis/PyQt/QtWidgets.py` (it contains https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/2d1aa68f0d044f2aced7ebeca8d2fa6b754ac970/python/PyQt/PyQt5/QtWidgets.py) and `include/qt/QtWidgets/QMainWindow` that `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *` look for it. In `C:\OSGeo4W64\bin`, you should find a `qt5_env.bat` that need to be loaded (see, the bat used to run QGIS to see how). Last part related to setting Pycharm to load correctly your env https://anitagraser.com/2019/03/03/stand-alone-pyqgis-scripts-with-osgeo4w/

Answer (score 2):

This is the simple PyQGIS application from the cookbook for the latest release, with all the imports that you say are failing for you included, and `/usr` as the QGIS prefix path which is where `QgsApplication.prefixPath()` says it is. This runs perfectly from a shell:

```
from qgis.core import *

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QUndoCommand, QUndoStack, QFileDialog, QVBoxLayout, QAction
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAbstractItemView, QMessageBox, QMenu, QInputDialog, QDockWidget


# Supply path to qgis install location
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)

# Create a reference to the QgsApplication.  Setting the
# second argument to False disables the GUI.
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)

# Load providers
qgs.initQgis()

# Write your code here to load some layers, use processing
# algorithms, etc.

# Finally, exitQgis() is called to remove the
# provider and layer registries from memory
qgs.exitQgis()
```

If this doesn't work for you then you must be missing either prerequisites (ie the PyQt5 stuff, which is *not* part of QGIS) or have a broken setup. You don't state you operating system or version of it, or any other aspects of your setup.

But I can state that PyQGIS standalone applications are not, are not planned to be, deprecated in any way, and that for me at least, those imports that don't work for you work perfectly for me.

Ubuntu 20.04 with qgis 3.20-latest etc installed via apt from qgis.org

Comment: I updated my question to give details of our setup. We started from QGIS 2.7, which has its own setup instruction which we followed to get everything working, then after QGIS moved into python 3, there is no official instruction anywhere. So we brute forced to migrate into python 3 version of QGIS using the same scheme after fixing many breaking changes in the QGIS libraries. What you showed here has been working with QGIS 3.6 version, but after we installed QGIS 3.16, it is NOT working anymore. Just see Kadir's reply, PyQt namespace is moved under qgis namespace with this new version!

Comment: Why is Kadir's answer removed?

Comment: So are you saying PyQt5 is not part of QGIS installation? then I don't know how that is possible as we have been developing using QGIS 3.6 and we used QGIS's own PyQt5 libraries and we do not have any other pyqt libraries on our development machine. The bottom line is, this code you posted worked fine when we were using QGIS 3.6 and we have not changed anything else except installing this new version of QGIS 3.16 and it is failing. So if it is due to missing prerequisites and that we've been using everything from QGIS installation, then this only points to new QGIS missing some prerequisites.

Comment: The PyQt5 library is *not* part of QGIS. It is an add-on library which you don't need to run QGIS - QGIS will run happily without *ANY* python support, for example.Depending on how you install QGIS you may or may not get it installed as a prerequisite, or you may need to install it afterwards.

Comment: The answer to your question - "Does QGIS still support standalone app dev?" is clearly **YES**. Its documented for the latest version of QGIS. That you can't get it to work is not evidence to the contrary. If you want help getting it to work, ask a new question, because this one - the question in your title - is answered.

Comment: Well, here is the thing, if QGIS truly support standalone application development, then there should be clear instructions, but the very much lacking of documentation from version to version and the ever changing QGIS distribution mechanism (hence different packaging as you evidently pointed out yourself: depends on how you install), pretty much makes standalone app development very unreliable, that's just what's happening in reality, regardless of whether QGIS merely saying yes or no.

Comment: QGIS is a piece of software that comes with no warranty. QGIS is not an entity that can "support" anything. If you want support for anything in QGIS you can pay for it and get support for it and get a warranty with that. If you want to improve standalone app support you can offer to pay for it, and someone - and because this is open source *anyone* - can take up your offer. But for most of us it seems the functionality is acceptable.

Comment: I guess we are talking about different things, when I say support, I meant that there ought to be some consistence in QGIS software library structure per standalone pyqgis application development and some form of documentation telling us that certain namespaces are moved or merged or eliminated or what not. In fact, threads like this one are precisely what's needed to deal with such issue and we are all doing it right now, aren't we? Look, at least two users gave out updated namespaces. I wonder if there should be a standard standalone app that gets run each time a new QGIS version is released

Comment: This is not a place for "threads". Its a Q+A site. You really should take this to the qgis-dev mailing list.